# Двусвязный список(проверка на удаление элемента)

Tags: c++, указатели, список

Попробовал сделать пародию на двусвязный список и получилось вот что:

```
struct privateNumber{
   int number;
   int countElement = 1;
   privateNumber* next;/// указатель на следующий элемент
   privateNumber* curr;/// указатель на текущий элемент
   privateNumber* pre;/// указатель на предыдущий элемент
};

privateNumber *address = NULL;
void addPrivateNumber(int getNumber)
{
   privateNumber *ptr = new privateNumber;
   ptr -> number = getNumber;
   ptr -> next = address;
   ptr -> curr = ptr;
   if(address != NULL)
   {
       ptr -> next -> pre = ptr;
       ptr -> countElement += ptr -> next -> countElement;
   }
   address = ptr;
}
void showPrivateNumber()
{
    privateNumber *i = address;
    while(i)
    {
       cout << "number[" << i -> countElement << "] = " << i -> number << endl;
       cout << "address[" << i -> curr << "]" << endl;
       cout << "address_next[" << i -> next << "]" << endl;
       cout << "address_pre[" << i -> pre << "]" << endl << endl;
       i = i -> next;
    }
   cout << endl;
}
 void deleteSearchValue(int value)
{
   privateNumber *ptrSearch = address;
   ///cout << ptrSearch -> next -> number << endl;
   while(ptrSearch -> number != value)
      ptrSearch = ptrSearch -> next;
   cout << ptrSearch -> number << endl;
   cout << "ptrSearch:[" << ptrSearch << "]" << endl;
   cout << "ptrSearch -> next:[" << ptrSearch -> next << "]" << endl;
   ptrSearch -> pre -> next = ptrSearch -> next;
}
int main()
{
    addPrivateNumber(57);
    addPrivateNumber(47);
    addPrivateNumber(12);
    addPrivateNumber(443);
    addPrivateNumber(32);
    addPrivateNumber(345);
    addPrivateNumber(125);
    deleteSearchValue(17);
    showPrivateNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Как проверить на то что удаляемой цифры нет?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Просматриваем с начала и если дошли до `NULL`, то цифры нет.

Comment: пробовал, но видимо я то ли не там писал, то ли не то сравнивал в любом случае если нету проверки на несуществущее число то программа крашится тк в функции удаления числа нет этой самой проверки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего нет никакого смысла определять член структуры `curr`. Он у вас нигде не используется.

В функции `addPrivateNumber` вы не устанавливаете значение поля `pre` добавляемого элемента. Это может стать причиной бага в других функциях, как, например, в функции `deleteSearchValue`.
Поэтому следует добавить данную инициализацию.

```
void addPrivateNumber(int getNumber)
{
   privateNumber *ptr = new privateNumber;
   ptr -> number = getNumber;
   ptr -> next = address;
   ptr -> curr = ptr;
   ptr -> pre  = NULL;

   if ( ptr -> next != NULL)
   {
       ptr -> next -> pre = ptr;
       ptr -> countElement += ptr -> next -> countElement;
   }
   address = ptr;
}
```

В функции `deleteSearchValue` нет проверки на то, что `address` может быть равен NULL.

Функция может быть написана следующим образом:

```
void deleteSearchValue( int value )
{
    privateNumber *ptrSearch = address;

    while ( ptrSearch != NULL && ptrSearch -> number != value )
        ptrSearch = ptrSearch -> next;

    if (  ptrSearch != NULL )
    {
        cout << ptrSearch -> number << endl;
        cout << "ptrSearch:[" << ptrSearch << "]" << endl;
        cout << "ptrSearch -> next:[" << ptrSearch -> next << "]" << endl;

        if ( ptrSearch -> pre != NULL )
        {
            ptrSearch -> pre -> next = ptrSearch -> next;
        }
        else
        { 
            address = ptrSearch -> next;
        }
        if ( ptrSearch -> next != NULL )
        {
            ptrSearch -> next -> pre = ptrSearch -> pre;
        } 

        delete ptrSearch;
    } 
}
```

Имейте в виду, что при удалении элемента у вас нарушается последовательность значений поля `countElement`, так как в ней появляются "дыры".

Вам также следует написать функцию, которая будет освобождать всю память, занимаемую списком, когда список уже не нужен.

Можно написать функцию, которая будет проверять, есть ли элемент в списке с заданным значением числа.

Например,

```
bool searchValue( int value )
{
    privateNumber *ptrSearch = address;

    while ( ptrSearch != NULL && ptrSearch -> number != value )
        ptrSearch = ptrSearch -> next;

    return  ptrSearch != NULL;
}
```

Comment: с первым багом я разобрался до вашего написания, но инициализировал в самой структуре, хотелось бы понять это : ptrSearch != NULL как компилятор поймет что мы вылетели из списка?
разве запись ptrSearch -> next != NULL будет не лучше?

Comment: @MaximPro Если ptrSearch равен NULL, то либо изначально в списке нет элементов, либо мы добрались до конца списка и не нашли требуемый элемент.

Comment: мне казалось что далее хранятся "случайные" адреса и только мы можем определять где надо остановиться        кстати я думаю что это условие не нужно if (ptrSearch != NULL) - без него все работает,
а тут я написал так  while (ptrSearch -> number != value && ptrSearch -> next != NULL)
        ptrSearch = ptrSearch -> next;
Тоже самое же по сути? или я не прав?

Comment: @MaximPro Как я уже сказал, изначально address может быть равен NULL. Попробуйте вызвать операцию удаления для пустого списка.

Comment: действительно! но я сделал так privateNumber *ptrSearch = address; if(ptrSearch == NULL)
        return;

Comment: @MaximPro Получается, что вы добавили дополнительное предложение с  проверкой, которая могла бы быть сделана в самом цикле while

Comment: у вас тоже стоит такая же проверка но после while

Comment: @MaximPro Проверка после while важна, так как она определяет, найден ли элемент или нет.

Comment: а у меня в начале проверка на то что вообще есть ли элементы, а вторая проверка в while, чтобы не вылететь если удаляемого числа не существует в списке

Comment: Наличие поля `countElement` (и алгоритм в `addPrivateNumber()`) заставляют предположить, что при удалении элемента списка нужен еще один цикл для корректировки этих полей в предшествующих удаляемому элементов списка / (уфф..., написать то же на Си, наверное быстрее (и  м.б. понятней))

Comment: @avp countElement создан для наглядности, ну знаете как в MySQL поле id, так и тут

Answer (score 2):

Не компилировал, ибо лень, но должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
bool deleteValue(int value)
{
    privateNumber* current = address;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->number == value) {
            if (current->pre != NULL)
                current->pre->next = current->next;
            if (current->next != NULL) 
                current->next->pre = current->pre;
            if (address == current)
                address = current->next;
            current = current->next;
            delete current;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Удаляет из списка первое вхождение указанного числа. Возвращает `true`, если число было и `false`, если нет.

Comment: ага понятно, правда я написал по-другому(два условия сразу писал а не по одному) и все таки смог без помощи  помочь себе, но ваш код тоже очень хорош, и поэтому я вам ставлю как ответ